# if (jQuery)(function ($) { . . .})(jQuery); plugin format

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I was looking at a plugin that has the format

```
if (jQuery)(function ($) { 
        -- plugin code --
})(jQuery);
```

I understand that

```
(function ($) { 
        -- plugin code --
})(jQuery);
```

is to make sure that $ refers to jQuery and not Prototype inside our function, but what does the

```
if (jQuery)
```

do for us?

Thanks

Comment: See http://jquery-howto.blogspot.in/2009/03/check-if-jqueryjs-is-loaded.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer and also for cluing me into jquery-howto.blogspot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if(jQuery)` part just makes sure that jQuery has been loaded before attempting to execute the plug-in code.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sure that jQuery is properly loaded. Also worth mentioning is that it's a self-executing function which will be invoked automatically.